# iText placement of Phrase within ColumnText

Tags: java, itext

So I'm dealing with a situation where I have a Phrase added to a ColumnText object.

[image: Text alignment issue]

The title in black is where iText is placing the text of the Phrase within the ColumnText.  The title in pink is the desired placement.

```
 private void addText(PdfContentByte contentByte, PdfReader threePagesReader, Project project, CoverTemplate coverTemplate)
        throws DocumentException {

    ColumnText columnText = new ColumnText(contentByte);

    // This only affects the space between Phrases, not the space between the top of the
    //ColumnText and the first Phrase
    int extraParagraphSpace = 12;
    columnText.setExtraParagraphSpace(extraParagraphSpace);

    Phrase mainTitle = new Phrase(project.getTitle(),buildCoverFont(coverTemplate.getFontSizeLine1()));
    columnText.addText(mainTitle);
       ... <other code that is not pertinent to this question>

    //these values are calculated from values that will place this columnText onto the PDF 
    //template
    columnText.setSimpleColumn(llx, lly, urx, ury);
    columnText.go();

private Font buildCoverFont(float fontSize) {
    Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FONT_ARIAL, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, fontSize, Font.NORMAL, CMYK_BLACK);
    BaseFont baseFont = font.getBaseFont();

    if (baseFont != null) {
        baseFont.setSubset(false); // fully embedded as per requirements
    }
    return font;
}
```

Is there anything I can do to tell iText not to put any space between the top of the highest glyphs (D and Z in this case) and the top of the ColumnText box?

I tried looking at the BaseFont.getAscension() to see if there was any value available, but it ended up 0 anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the [ColumnTextAscender](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/ColumnTextAscender) example:

[image]

In both cases, I have drawn a red rectangle:

```
rect.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
rect.setBorderWidth(0.5f);
rect.setBorderColor(BaseColor.RED);
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
cb.rectangle(rect);
```

To the left, you see the text added the way you do. In this case, iText will add extra space commonly known as the *leading*. To the right, you see the text added the way you want to add it. In this case, we have told the `ColumnText` that it needs to use the Ascender value of the font:

```
Phrase p = new Phrase("This text is added at the top of the column.");
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
ct.setSimpleColumn(rect);
ct.setUseAscender(true);
ct.addText(p);
ct.go();
```

Now the top of the text touches the border of the rectangle.

Comment: Thanks! That was immensely helpful, much appreciated.