# Add paragraph dynamically at the bottom with iText library in android

Tags: android, itext

I am using below code but this is not working its show only one line in bottom while I want a paragraph in bottom in every page.

```
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
          Rectangle rect = writer.getBoxSize("art");
          ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
                  Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(ActivityWaTestamentInput.pDFHeaderText,headerFont),
                  rect.getLeft(), rect.getTop(), 0);
          ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
                  Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Paragraph(ActivityWaTestamentInput.pDFFooterText,footerFont),
                  rect.getLeft() , rect.getBottom() - 18, 0);
```

Comment: Hi @AkashKumaSingh, I didn't see any response (and the answer wasn't accepted). Didn't you succeed in applying my answer?

Comment: Post docs to `iText` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented, `ColumnText.showTextAligned()` will only show one line. If you need multiple lines, then you can also use `ColumnText`, but you need to use it in a different way.

Please download the free ebook [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html). In the section "Absolute positioning of text", you'll find several examples that involve `ColumnText`.

These are some questions and answers you should check:

- [How to fit a String inside a rectangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526043/how-to-fit-a-string-inside-a-rectangle)
- [How to draw a rectangle around multiline text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037981/how-to-draw-a-rectangle-around-multiline-text)
- [iText placement of Phrase within ColumnText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27906725/itext-placement-of-phrase-within-columntext)

This is a code snippet from one of the answers to these questions:

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
ct.setSimpleColumn(120f, 500f, 250f, 780f);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("This is a long paragraph that doesn't"
    + "fit the width we defined for the simple column of the" 
    + "ColumnText object, so it will be distributed over several"
    + "lines (and we don't know in advance how many).");
ct.addElement(p);
ct.go();
```

I hardcoded the position:

```
llx = 120;
lly = 500;
urx = 250;
ury = 780;
```

This is a rectangle with lower left corner (120, 500), a width of 130 and a height of 380. You will need to adapt these values if you want the text to appear at the bottom of the page.